# Computing a product of values based on another vector bit values using SIMD

Tags: c++, performance, sse, simd

I have two vectors. A vector of doubles `a` of size `N` and a vector of unsigned characters `b` of size `ceil(N/8)`. The goal is to compute of product of some of the values of `a`. `b` is to be read on a bit-by-bit basis, where each bit indicate whether given `double` from `a` is to be considered in the product.

```
  // Let's create some data      
  unsigned nbBits  = 1e7;
  unsigned nbBytes = nbBits / 8;
  unsigned char nbBitsInLastByte = nbBits % 8;
  assert(nbBits == nbBytes * 8 + nbBitsInLastByte);
  std::vector<double> a(nbBits, 0.999999);   // In practice a values will vary. It is just an easy to build example I am showing here
  std::vector<unsigned char> b(nbBytes, false); // I am not using `vector<bool>` nor `bitset`. I've got my reasons!
  assert(a.size() == b.size() * 8);

  // Set a few bits to true
  for (unsigned byte = 0 ; byte < (nbBytes-1) ; byte+=2)
  {
    b[byte] |= 1 << 2; // set second (zero-based counting) bit to 'true'
    b[byte] |= 1 << 7; // set last bit to 'true'
                //  ^ This is the bit index
  }
```

As explained above, my goal is to compute a product of the values in `a` whenever `b` is true. It can be achieved with

```
  // Initialize the variable we want to compute
  double product = 1.0;

  // Product for the first nbByts-1 bytes
  for (unsigned byte = 0 ; byte < (nbBytes-1) ; ++byte)
  {
    for (unsigned bit = 0 ; bit < 8 ; ++bit) // inner loop could be manually unrolled
    {
      if((b[byte] >> bit) & 1) // gets the bit value
        product *= a[byte*8+bit];
    }
  }

  // Product for the last byte
  for (unsigned bit = 0 ; bit < nbBitsInLastByte ; ++bit)
  {
    if((b[nbBytes-1] >> bit) & 1) // gets the bit value
      product *= a[(nbBytes-1)*8+bit];
  }
```

This product computation is the slow part of my code. I am wondering whether explicitly vectorizing (SIMD) the process can be of help here. I have been looking at the functions provided in the 'xmmintrin.h' but I don't know much about SIMD and I failed to find something that would be of help. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you enable your compilers optimizer? If not, do so. If you are lucky, the compiler *might* be able to vectorize the code for you. For gcc or clang, test builds with the `-O2` or `-O3` options. For MSVC, try `/O2`.

Comment: I use both gcc and clang with `-O3` so, it should attempt to vectorize the code for me. I am not able to verify whether it actually successfully vectorize it though.

Comment: look at the generated assembly.. [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) makes that super easy, but you can also just ask your local compiler to dump asm.

Comment: how many doubles in the vector?

Comment: Do you just have SSE (SSE2, SSE3, SSE4?) or AVX(2) as well? Is the bitvector completely "random" or does it often have sequences of all 0 or all 1 bits?

Comment: So you're doing a masked reduction using `mul` instead of the more-common `add`.  Related: [Fast dot product of a bit vector and a floating point vector](//stackoverflow.com/q/16051365) and I think I remember a more recent float * boolean dot product question (which of course also boils down to a masked reduction of the float vector.  Oh, found it: [Vector matrix multiplication, float vector, binary matrix](//stackoverflow.com/q/58380272), less relevant than I remembered.  See also [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36488675)

Comment: @AhmedAnter There are anywhere between about 10 to about 1e7 or even 1e8 values in `a`. The size is not necessarily a multiple of anything.

Comment: how long does it take with you?

Comment: @chtz Most of the time, the bitvector will look like a perfectly random sequence of zeros and ones. Most of the time, there will be less than 1% of ones and there will very rarely be more than 10% of ones. I plan to run the code on different machine but unless I am mistaken all machines used today have at least SSE and SSE2. Maybe I should not aim higher than that.

Comment: @AhmedAnter The process can take up to 60% of the total running time of my process. I don't know by heart how much time every iteration takes.

Comment: I did run this code on my pc it took about 80ms and gives result is this slow for you?

Comment: With that few ones, I would first consider adding a `if(b[byte]==0) continue;` at the beginning of your outer loop (that would be true about 92% of the time). And for the `!=0` case, maybe do a switch for each (half of a) byte, with some hand-tuned implementations. Latency of multiplication is probably not an issue, but branch-prediction is. If your bit-pattern was random with about 50% ones, consider one of the options Peter linked to.

Comment: @AhmedAnter I am sorry, I don't remember. I am on my laptop right now and it makes testing with big enough parameter values a little tricky!

Comment: @chtz: multiply latency is potentially significant!  A modern x86 has a factor of 8 or 10 difference in multiply latency vs. throughput.  Even overhead of bitmap -> vector mask won't necessarily hide 4 to 5 cycles of latency per multiply.

Comment: Just realized that simply masking like you would for `add` doesn't work: the identity element for multiply is `1.0` not `0.0`.  So you might have to blend in a `1.0`.  (With AVX512, merge-masking into the destination still Just Works).  Without AVX512, you probably want to blend a 1.0 into the inputs instead of adding latency to the multiply dep chain by blending in the old value of the vector.  Anyway, yes, branching on a whole group of mask bits being all zero is worth trying.  And yes, SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.  AVX and AVX2 are common but you can't assume it except on server-side stuff

Comment: @PeterCordes I assume you are right. I'm always unsure about the impact of false branch predictions. But I guess, it's better to make a masked/blended multiplication to 4 registers in the inner loop (instead of doing a switch, as I originally suggested) -- very hard to say without knowing the actual bit-pattern (or architecture).

Comment: @chtz: branch-mispredict penalty for the front-end can be something like 10 to 15 cycles, during which time you could maybe do 10 * 2 * 4 double-precision multiplies with AVX.  So if you were front-end bottlenecked you'd potentially lose a lot of throughput.  But with a back-end throughput bottleneck, an early out based on this check that's off the critical path could just give the back end some time to catch up without losing much throughput. (On Nehalem or later with fast-recovery for branch misses, not waiting until the branch reaches retirement). Hand-wavy; have to benchmark with real data

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t care about multiplication order, it’s easy. The key is `_mm_blendv_pd` instruction from SSE 4.1 set. This allows you to go completely branchless.

```
// Load 2 double values from source pointer, and conditionally multiply with the product.
// Returns the new product.
template<int startIdx>
inline __m128d product2( const double* pSource, __m128i mask, __m128d oldProduct )
{
    // Multiply values unconditionally
    const __m128d source = _mm_loadu_pd( pSource + startIdx );
    const __m128d newProduct = _mm_mul_pd( source, oldProduct );

    // We only calling product2 with 4 different template arguments.
    // There are 16 vector registers in total, enough for all 4 different `maskAndBits` values.
    constexpr int64_t bit1 = 1 << startIdx;
    constexpr int64_t bit2 = 1 << ( startIdx + 1 );
    const __m128i maskAndBits = _mm_setr_epi64x( bit1, bit2 );
    mask = _mm_and_si128( mask, maskAndBits );

    // NAN if the mask is 0 after the above AND i.e. the bit was not set, 0.0 if the bit was set
    const __m128d maskDouble = _mm_castsi128_pd( _mm_cmpeq_epi64( mask, _mm_setzero_si128() ) );

    // This instruction actually does the masking, it's from SSE 4.1
    return _mm_blendv_pd( newProduct, oldProduct, maskDouble );
}

double conditionalProducts( const double* ptr, const uint8_t* masks, size_t size )
{
    // Round down the size of your input vector, and multiply last couple values the old way.
    assert( 0 == size % 8 );
    __m128d prod = _mm_set1_pd( 1.0 );
    const double* const end = ptr + size;
    while( ptr < end )
    {
        // Broadcast the mask byte into 64-bit integer lanes
        const __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi64x( *masks );
        // Compute the conditional products of 8 values
        prod = product2<0>( ptr, mask, prod );
        prod = product2<2>( ptr, mask, prod );
        prod = product2<4>( ptr, mask, prod );
        prod = product2<6>( ptr, mask, prod );
        // Advance the pointers
        ptr += 8;
        masks++;
    }
    // Multiply two lanes together
    prod = _mm_mul_sd( prod, _mm_shuffle_pd( prod, prod, 0b11 ) );
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64( prod );
}
```

Comment: Since bendv_pd only uses 64th and 128th bits as a condition I was about a different solution. It should be possible to just convert the uint8_t mask to uint64_t, shift it by 2 different amounts such that the relevant bit ends up on the 64th and 128th bit, and `_mm_setr_epi64x`

Comment: @Sopel Not sure I follow. There’re 8 relevant bits in the mask. Do you propose to copy values from GP registers to vector registers 4 times instead of just 1?  Both `pand` and `pcmpeqq` in my code have 1 cycle latency / each.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/WxG8Cz Not sure if can be done efficiently without AVX2 because there is no `sll` with counts per lane. `const __m128i mulmask = _mm_sllv_epi64(mask, _mm_set_epi64x((63 - startIdx), (63 - ( startIdx + 1 ))));` gets the relevant condition bit into the highest bit of 64 bit lane - one checked by blendv

Comment: @Sopel I’m not sure your code is faster. That AVX2 instruction, `vpsllvq`, is not particularly fast on most CPUs except Skylake. It has 2 cycles latency on Haswell & Broadwell, 3 cycles latency on Ryzen. Throughput is not great either, and it decodes into 2-3 µops. Both `pand` and `pcmpeqq` in my code decode into single µop/each, they have 1 cycle latency, and the throughput is good, they can run 2-3 times per cycle. The bit mask stuff has no data dependencies across the 4 calls to product2, the pipelining will hopefully do the job.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I have not benchmarked it, just an idea.

Comment: @Sopel I haven’t benchmarked either, just reading the manual. BTW you can too: https://github.com/Const-me/IntelIntrinsics

Comment: Just one more SSE version if someone would make benchmarks, similar but <<1 is taken at the beginning so sllv is not needed. Also 4 separate accumulators for the products to remove dependencies. https://godbolt.org/z/f7PDPe

Comment: @Sopel Nice! I would use `_mm_slli_epi64` instead of `_mm_sll_epi64`, their speed is the same, but immediate shift saves 4 vector registers. Also I’m not sure about this `_mm_set_epi64x( *masks << 1, *masks )` You probably need to shift the mask `>>` direction by that 1 bit, for the higher of the 2 lanes. https://godbolt.org/z/YHfgeh

Comment: I'd put the blend latency as part of each independent input, not on the critical path.  Or just use enough accumulators since you want multiple anyway to hide FP mul latency.

Comment: Ideally we'd only need 1 instruction to shift a vector of mask data to line up a new pair of mask bits at the top of each qword element.  Without rotate, maybe we can go in reverse order from the end of a block of vectors, if that doesn't defeat HW prefetch too badly.  Otherwise bit-reverse mask data before a block of multiplies.  e.g. load mask data with a 32-bit or 64-bit broadcast load (like `movddup`).  Then left-shift only the high half (or low half if you haven't bit-reversed) by adding it to itself with one half zeroed.  `m+0 = m` and `m+m = m<<1`.  Hmm, maybe `movq` load + `pshufd`+add